# Android realtime connection

Tags: android, sockets, google-cloud-messaging, connection, xmpp

So to describe my problem: I would like to be able to send the current position of a finger on one phones screen to the other, kind of like "remote control" although the finger location will only be plotted on the other screen and not for controling it.

I've been looking into a solution on how to open and keep the connection between the phones and so far I haven't found any way that I think is suitable to send the data repeatedly.

1. **Socket Connection** - not suitable becuase if the IP address changes the connection is lost.
2. **XMPP/FCM** - not sutiable due to limit in "messages" being sent (?)

How does the game(s) where one person draws on one screen and it's instantly visible on the other connected peoples screen work using android?

How does *beammessanger* work?

I think both of the applications above needs to have a soultion for this problem since they are "instantly" displaying changes between multiple phones.

Anyone got any information on where I should look to get a better understanding on how to solve my problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve this you need to have a server which supports socket connection. Also you need a push implementation in your app.

This typically shud work as follows when user A wants to communicate to user B.

- User A connects to server via socket and tells the server it is interested in communicating with user B.
- If user B is connected to the server via socket, server establishes a comm link between user A and user B.
- If user B is not connected to server then server sends a push notification to user B.
- Now user B android application receives the push and knows someone is interested in communicating hence establishes a socket connection with server.
- Now comm link is established by the server between both the users.